# Is it illegal to create a website that allow a user to upload a file and make it accessible and downloadable for others?

Tags: security, legal, copyright

I am working on a website in which a user can sign in and upload a file and other users can search for it by name and download it. Those files will be catagorized as audio, video, apps(linux, windows, mac), documents etc. So, I was wondering if it is legal or illegal. I'll also add a "report" option with each file by which visitors can report a pirated content.

Comment: Be careful! Any user can upload a file that is copyrighted. Make sure you have a take down process that is paid attention to and responded to very quickly.

Comment: Sorry, but this is too broad and opinion-based for this site. It depends on what files are uploaded and if they are copyright protected...

Comment: @dan Thanks for the hat! I am wearing it now. Merry Christmas / Happy Holidays my friend and to everyone here. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Building a website where people can share files is not illegal.

If people upload content where the copyright is owned by someone else and they don't have permission to share it, then that is illegal and they are responsible.

If you then share that content, *you* become responsible.

Comment: And what about thepiratebay? I've heard that it is illegal

Comment: Do your research.  TPB doesn't host any files at all, it is simply a search engine.